# Laravel 4 - Dingo authentication with OAuth 2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, oauth-2.0

I am a little bit confused on how to use OAuth 2.0 with the [Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api). I've never used OAuth in a project before, but basically I'm trying to create a private REST API, and I'm currently trying to implement a fairly simple user system. Can someone explain to me what I can and can't do with OAuth and Dingo?

Comment: Just a suggestion: Your question is way too vague.  You're not going to get someone on here to write up a tutorial for you (there are plenty of OAuth tutorials on the Internet for you to read).  I would suggest amending your question with a code snippet, if you've run into a specific problem while trying to implement this yourself.